# SASS throws an error Undefined Mixins: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): SassError: Undefined mixin

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I am working a react project and when I tried to use a mixin like @include it gave a compiling error:

```
  ╷
7 │ ┌   @include mobile {
8 │ │     flex-direction: column;
9 │ └   }

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined mixin.
```

I have installed the packages and checked to see if it wasnt installed properly I still get this error what can I do?

code:

```
@import "../../global.scss";

.contact {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;

  @include mobile {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .left {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: hidden;

    img {
      height: 100%;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What does your file structure look like?

Answer (score 3):

The mixin `mobile` is resolved only by name without the use of `explicit imports`.
When using sass variable, mixin, or function declared in another file It is recommended to explicitly import them to the current file like:

```
@use "../../global.scss" as s;

.contact{ 
 @include s.mobile {
   flex-direction: column;
 }
}
```

And also the `Sass` team discourages the use of the `@import` rule, Prefer the combination of `@use` and `@forward` rules instead. [read the doc for more.](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import)